# How to copy files into the singularity sandbox?

Tags: linux

I have been generate a singularity sandbox on the host dir "ubuntu_latest/", how can I cp some files into the container dir ?

I try to use “singularity --bind” or “singularity --exec” to cp files, but it doesn't matter.